# Notification at specific time error

Tags: android, xml, permissions, notifications

I'm trying to make a simple app that make a notification at specific time for example ( 4:25 pm )

But when my mobile get 4:25 pm the notification doesn't appear

I don't know what is the problem

That is the code

MainActivity.class

```
 package com.example.notifi;

 import java.util.Calendar;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.AlarmManager;
 import android.app.PendingIntent;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Notificationmassage.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
 }
 }
```

Activity_main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Notificationmassage.class

```
 package com.example.notifi;

 import android.app.Notification;
 import android.app.NotificationManager;
 import android.app.PendingIntent;
 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
 import android.util.Log;

 public class Notificationmassage extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    showNotification(context);
}

private void showNotification(Context context) {
    Log.i("notification", "visible");

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, Notificationmassage.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("xyz")
            .setContentText("It will contain dummy content");
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
}  
 }
```

manifist

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.notifi"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="com.example.notifi.Notificationmassage"></receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

This is all my code

I don't know where is the error

Please help

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `explicit intent` in this case, you have to use `implicit intent`

`new Intent(context, Notificationmassage.class)` is `explicit intent`

You should change it to `implicit intent`, i.e. `new Intent("com.example.notifi.NOTIFI_RECEIVER")`

and you need to define your BroadcastReceiver in manifest

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.notifi.Notificationmassage" >
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.example.notifi.NOTIFI_RECEIVER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```